# External logins and c# web api

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to .NET core and while I have .NET experience, I have never built authentication, in the past I've always worked on project not started by me. I am just trying to learn and find good resources and I would greatly appreciate if anyone knows tutorial or if it can explain how to solve this.

When using external logins, I followed those instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2). This all works well if I create simple web api project and run, I get a web page where I can login, authenticate, works perfect. But this is not my end goal, I am building Web APIs not a Web Application. In my case let's say I have iOS and Android apps and my external login is done on the app itself, how would I pass token to Web APIs? I want to use [Authorize] method in Web APIs to make sure that no un-authorized access is made agains APIs and in addition to that I would like to use roles.

I am assuming token information is passed in header. But what is the header name for token? Can external authentication be used with roles or that is only possible if I store username/password? Can you point me to some good tutorial or anywhere I can learn more because all google search returns back to same like I have mentioned above and it is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general , your web api will work like a identity provider , it will issue and validate the JWT tokens :

http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

You can also implement authorization with the help of your external login provider .If you have SDK or own code in your client app to help do authentication , for authorization part , you can also register your web api in the same identity provider . For example , you are using the google authentication external login in your client app , you will should register your client app and web api on google's application registration page , then you could use OpenID Connect hybrid Flow to authentication user and get access token for accessing web api . Each identity provider provides how to implement authentication/authorization with lots of documents.

Comment: This tutorial is exactly what I was looking for to get into more details about the topic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can have an endpoint that allows anonymous access and takes the token and verifies it. Then it can send back a JWT that contains claims/roles that you want to enforce on the specific user. Every time the client accesses a secure endpoint, it can send your JWT in the header which gets verified before the specific method in your API controller is called. You can look into OAuth flows if you want to integrate social logins.
For example, Google has this documentation for OAuth-
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth